# VB.net - Faster text manipulation/storing to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance, visual-studio, io

I have to make a program that reads .txt files for a string, and manipulates the data to return various results.
The problem that I have is with the timing of the execution.

```
    Dim OpenAnswerFile As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenAnswerFile.Multiselect = True
    Dim strFileName() As String '// String Array.
    Dim tempStr As String = "" '// temp String for result.
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Watcher As New Stopwatch
    If OpenAnswerFile.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 
        Watcher.Restart()
        For Each FileName In OpenAnswerFile.FileNames

            strFileName = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName) 
            For Each myLine In strFileName 
                tempStr &= myLine & vbNewLine 
            Next

        Next
        Watcher.Stop()
        Dim TimeToArrays = Watcher.Elapsed
        Watcher.Reset()
        '========================WRITE TO FILE
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
        Watcher.Restart()
        file.Write(tempStr)
        file.WriteLine(TimeToArrays)
        file.WriteLine(Watcher.Elapsed)
        Watcher.Stop()
        file.Close()

        '========================WRITE TO FILE

    End If
```

Running this to dictionary-styled txt files, from A to Z, takes about a minute, which I find a lot for a total of just over 1MB of files.

Is there any way to speed-up the whole process?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the files without storing them all in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code - it runs in 6.5 seconds on nearly 90Mb of files.

Changes to your code can be summarised as:

- Check the DialogResult and don't iterate the files until this part of the routine is complete.
- During the read operations, use the `Using...End Using` to make the IO efficient.
- Use a `List(of String)` to hold the data rather than keep appending to a String. I think this is more efficient from a memory management point of view. There may be quicker ways using other collections.
- During the write operation use the `Using...End Using` to make the IO efficient.

Here's the code:

```
Sub DoItQuicker()

    Dim OpenAnswerFile As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenAnswerFile.Multiselect = True
    Dim strFileName() As String '// String Array.
    Dim strSingleFileContent As String
    Dim strFileData As New List(Of String)
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Watcher As New Stopwatch

    'get user feedback
    If OpenAnswerFile.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not OK")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        strFileName = OpenAnswerFile.FileNames
    End If
    OpenAnswerFile.Dispose()

    'read data
    Watcher.Restart()
    For Each FileName In OpenAnswerFile.FileNames

        Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(FileName)
            strSingleFileContent = sr.ReadToEnd
            For Each line As String In strSingleFileContent.Split(vbLf)
                strFileData.Add(line)
            Next
        End Using

    Next
    Watcher.Stop()
    Dim TimeToArrays = Watcher.Elapsed
    Debug.Print(Watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds)

    'write data
    Watcher.Restart()
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("D:\temp\out.txt")
        For Each line As String In strFileData
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        sw.WriteLine(TimeToArrays)
        sw.WriteLine(Watcher.Elapsed)
    End Using
    Watcher.Stop()
    Debug.Write(Watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds)


End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested it, and it ran at 0.09s, down from ~1m using my code. Thank you very much.

But, a problem that I have using this code is that the output stores each letter in its own line. How can I store one whole word per line?

Comment: What's a sample content of each file? I generated some test files with thousands of rows of `foo,bar` just for testing.

Comment: https ://we .tl/beABagB9cI

I have upload a file in WeTransfer, for you to see what I am running it on.
It works really great, it only saves the .txt file by writing each letter to a new line

Edit: It also seems to leave 2 empty lines after each processed word

Comment: @SpK see my edit - the code now splits on vbLf which is the delimiter in your word list. So the entire sub should work for your A Words, B Words, C Words... Z Words files and compile into a single file of a long list of words. HTH.